# TableLayout orientation : only one column is showing in portrait orientation

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-orientation

I have created a table layout with two columns , it works fine with landscape orientation : 
[image: landcape]

But only one column is showing in portrait orientation :

[image: protrait]

I tried creating two folders layout-land & layout-port , and putting the xml file inside each one of them but it didn't work .

Here is the part pf the code with table layout :

```
 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/roundshape"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" 
            >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="6"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Octave schedule"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="serif" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Event" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="date                                           " >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Participants’ Briefing"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="25dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="date"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        style="@style/btnStyleGrey"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="25dip"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar2" />
                </LinearLayout>
                      ......
            </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using *android:layout_weight* with 0.75 for the textViews and 0.25 for the linear layout containing the imageButton and the editText .